# On Windows, how can i restore all minimized windows (maximize) with Win+M shortcut? (make Win+M a toggle)

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Is it possible somehow to minimize AND maximize (like a toggle) with Win+M shortcut?

Comment: It's possible to write a AutoHotKey that will transform every second Win+M to Win+Shift+M, but this solution seems a bit too heavy for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for your toggle. Win+M does not do this.

Comment: But if you use any other Win shortcut it stops the toggle functionality of the previous Win+D session, while Shift+Win+M  always works making it reliable.

Comment: Shift Win M does not do anything for me on Windows 10...

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10

search for "Restore minimized windows on the desktop"

Comment: I see that, but on two different Win10 machines, that shortcut does nothing for me.